# How to refer to a column alias in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare an alias (which has white spaces in it) with a white space in WHERE clause.

```
select r.resortid, sum(b.adultcount+b.childcount) as "Total Guest"
from   resort r, booking b
where  r.resortid = b.resortid and "Total Guest" <= 10
group by r.resortid
order by r.resortid;
```

The error I get is:

```
where  r.resortid=b.resortid and "Total Guest" <=10
                                 *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "Total Guest": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Having`, not `where`; also, `JOIN` wouldn't do any harm.

```
select r.resortid, 
       sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount) as "Total Guest"
from resort r join booking b on r.resortid = b.resortid 
group by r.resortid
having sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount) <= 10
order by r.resortid;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `HAVING` Clause & use explicit standard `JOIN` syntax instead of comma separate :

```
SELECT r.resortid, SUM(b.adultcount+b.childcount)
FROM resort r INNER JOIN
     booking b
     ON r.resortid = b.resortid 
GROUP BY r.resortid
HAVING SUM(b.adultcount+b.childcount) <= 10;
```

`Where` clause filter only raw data not after aggregation of data.

Answer (score 2):

Given that a resort *could* have no bookings, I would recommend a `left join`:

```
select r.resortid, coalesce(sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount), 0) as total_guests
from resort r join
     booking b 
     on r.resortid = b.resortid 
group by r.resortid
having coalesce(sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount), 0) <= 10
order by r.resortid;
```

If all resorts have bookings, then the `join` is not necessary:

```
select b.resortid, sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount) as total_guests
from booking b 
group by b.resortid
having sum(b.adultcount + b.childcount) <= 10
order by r.resortid;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to an alias in the condition defined in the same sql statement.

You have 3 possibility in Oracle/MariaDB/MySQL databases:

1) Rewrite calculated column and, if it's calculated by aggregation function, you have to put the condition in "HAVING" clause:

```
SELECT r.resortid, sum(b.adultcount+b.childcount) as "Total Guest"
  FROM resort r, booking b
 WHERE r.resortid = b.resortid
 GROUP BY r.resortid
  HAVING sum(b.adultcount+b.childcount) <= 10
ORDER BY r.resortid;
```

2) Using subquery:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT r.resortid, sum(b.adultcount+b.childcount) as TotalGuest
      FROM resort r, booking b
     WHERE r.resortid = b.resortid
     GROUP BY r.resortid) AS totalg
 WHERE TotalGuest <= 10
ORDER BY resortid;
```

3) Write subquery using "WITH" clause:

```
WITH totalg AS
(SELECT r.resortid, sum(b.adultcount+b.childcount) as TotalGuest
  FROM resort r, booking b
 WHERE r.resortid = b.resortid
GROUP BY r.resortid)
SELECT *
  FROM totalg
 WHERE TotalGuest <= 10
ORDER BY resortid;
```